# xCode Inellisense not showing up for UIPopoverController

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, intellisense

Does anyone know why my xCode intellisense does not show up when I type in UIPopoverCont...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been an ongoing issue.  Please open a bug report with Apple if one doesn't already exist.  BTW, for non-microsoft stuff it has usually been called things like "autocomplete" or "code completion".  MS just had to make their own trademark for the common feature back in the day.